HttpWebRequest / WebClient returning content length of 0
I have two URL's that both return same object structure when pasted in a browser.
• One URL will work with C# HttpWebRequest and WebClient protocols. One URL will not.
• Both return 200 OK
• Both work with Ajax
Here is a simple fiddle that demonstrates the anomaly.
strContent works
StrNoContent does not work.
Both work when pasted into a browser
https://dotnetfiddle.net/NBiXJR
I expected content to return for both. Would LOVE to know why the second one won't work.

the first one works fine, but the second one does not work probably, ensure you're using the correct querystring.  if you just add searchtext=hanes to the first one, it will return the same result as the second one.

Thank you for testing. I just tried that and I did not get any results.

Then that's your answer to your question. Just test the api using Postman or any alternative API testing tools, then if you're happy with the results, move it to your code and test it out there too.

Most likely a headers issue: Fiddler or some other transparent proxy will tell you the difference between one and the other. WebClient and HttpWebRequest are both deprecated, use HttpClient instead.

Thank you both for taking the time to respond. I have tried RestClient. I have tried HttpClient. I have tried everything. This works in Chrome Poster. This works in Rester. This works if you paste the link directly into the browser. It still, no matter what, always returns Content 0 in all of the afore mentioned protocols. I would LOVE to see a fiddle of this working.
